# Fixed position for the middle flex item to center

Tags: css, flexbox

I have multiple flex items inside a flex container with  `justify-content: space-between;`

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Each flex item is randomly with different size. What I want is for the middle item (number) to be always centered

This is what I  achieved for now:

[image]

And what I want is (I don't want the items nor the number/timer to be overlapped because I want the timer to be readable and the items to be draggable):

[image]

Is that doable using flexbox? Or should I use position fixed for each item

Comment: can you post your html, css and js?

Comment: If the number is an image you could set it as background to the container. If it is not an image you could use absolute positioning on it only and center it.

Comment: @Dejan.S its a react app with multiple components (using typescript - redux and some othrer tools).

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli its not an image. The problem with absolute positioning is that the other items overlap the number (timer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this could work. You have a wrapper, put the counter (or what it is) outside your list of icons. This is done in a hurry but you get the point?

The z-index puts the icons above the counter.

**EDIT:** Made the split for the logos. Note, this is one possible way of doing this. In your wanted image it seems as it is more dynamic, and for that you might need to do something with absolute positioning on some of the items (with their own class), I added example of that.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 20rem;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.counter {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.logos {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.logos>.logo {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.logo {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.logo-item--ice-cream {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  right: -2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: deeppink;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logos">
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo">
    x
      <span class="logo-item--ice-cream">x</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="counter">00:20</div>

  <div class="logos">
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
    <span class="logo"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is what i did before. But I dont want the number or the items to be overlapped

Comment: @PanagiotisKoursaris well your "wanted" image is overlapping. One solution would be to split the icons in two divs and have the "counter" in the middle. Another would be to look into grid, specifily grid-areas.

Comment: I thought for grid but I dont try with it because is not fully supported from the browsers. Maybe I will try with splirting the items to divs as you say.

Comment: @PanagiotisKoursaris what is your browser requirement. Grid is fully supported by all modern browsers. The split approach seem to be a valid one, you could make it a bit more dynamic by put negative margin on both divs to kinda bring them to overlap the counter a bit, just like in your image.

Comment: this will run on the browser on mobile devices. maybe if someone has an old phone the grid will not work. what do you think?

Comment: I will be appreciated if you could update your answer also with the grid way or with spliting the items

Comment: @PanagiotisKoursaris Do fallback for grid, I use flex for mine but it could be table (just css properties not table layout like <table>) or floats. The mindset is that it is OK that it doesn't look exactly the same on ie11 or older mobile browsers. I updated the question with the split. As I wrote in the edit, your image is more dynamic and mabye you should spend some time on making it so. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute should handle the issue:

```css
.absoulte {
  position: absolute;
}

.color-yellow {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 200px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-start { align-self: flex-start; }
.flex-end { align-self: flex-end; }
.center { align-self: center;}
.baseline { align-self: baseline; }
.stretch { align-self: stretch; }

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item center absoulte color-yellow">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex-end">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex-start">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item baseline">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item stretch">5</li>
</ul>
```